# How to fetch active users' products? (product belongs_to user)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

`User has_many products`

`Product belongs_to user`

User also has an `active_account` column in its table.

I am trying to translate this into a query:

'What products exist where the user that the product belongs to has an active account?'

The is the best I could get:

```
Product.find(where(user.active_account => 'True'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `active_account` is a boolean column in the `users` table:

```
Product.joins(:user).where(users: {active_account: true})
```

Comment: thank you! I actually need a slight variation of this question, I re-posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29054249/how-to-fetch-active-or-free-trial-users-products-product-belongs-to-user