# How to fetch active or free trial users' products? (product belongs_to user)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

```
User has_many products

Product belongs_to user
```

User also has an active_account and created_at column in its table.

I am trying to translate this into a query:

'What products exist where the user that the product belongs to has an active account OR is less than 25 days old?'

This is what I have so far (not sure how to add in the OR less than 25 days old):

```
Product.joins(:user).where(users: {active_account: true})
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way is to use [Arel](https://github.com/rails/arel)

```
users = Arel::Table.new(:users)
products = Arel::Table.new(:products)    
users
 .join(products,Arel::Nodes::InnerJoin)
 .on(users[:id].eq(products[:user_id]))
 .where(users[:active_account].eq(true).or(users[:created_at].lt(25.days.ago))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 Product.joins(:user).where("users.active_account = ? OR users.created_at >= '#{(Time.now - 25.days).utc.iso8601}'", true)
```

Comment: Saying this: NoMethodError: undefined method `or' for #<AmazonProduct::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x0....

Comment: Yes, I am testing and I have the same error. Try with using Arel as first question

Answer (score 0):

I would start with something like this:

```
Product.joins(:user).where(
  "users.active_account = :account_active OR users.created_at >= :max_age",
  { :account_active => true, :max_age => 25.days.ago }
)
```

---

In a next step I would move that logic into scopes and [merge](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods/merge) that scopes:

```
# in user.rb
scope :active, ->{
  where("users.active_account = :account_active OR users.created_at >= :max_age", { :account_active => true, :max_age => 25.days.ago })
}

# in product.rb
scope :with_active_user, ->{ joins(:user).merge(User.active) }
```

What allows you to use it like this:

```
Product.with_active_user
```